# Datareader not displaying first row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader, datareader

I am looping through my database to display a list of leagues a player is associated with. If a player is not a member of any leagues then a message displays to tell them.

Here is the code

```
if (dReader.Read())
{          
    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        usersLeagues.Text += "<li class=\"li-myLeagues\"><a  href=\"leagueDetails.aspx?leagueID=" + (dReader["leagueID"].ToString()) + "\">" + (dReader["leagueName"].ToString()) + "</a></li>";
    }
}
else
{
    usersLeagues.Text = "You are currently not a part of any leagues";
}
dReader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

The issue is that the data reader is not displaying the first league in the query.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Although this is purely a guess, I'll have to check the documentation for the method, I imagine you're losing the first row with your "if" conditional. You will probably need another method to see if data was returned.

Comment: Remove this if (dReader.Read()) it will work fine, no need to write this, if there is no data it will not enter while loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
if (dReader.Read()){
```

to

```
if (dReader.HasRows){
```

By calling the `Read()` in the `if` statement, you actually are reading the first row of data. Calling `Read()` again in the `while` statement, skips the first read row.

You can use [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.hasrows.aspx) property to check if the reader contains any data.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is reading the first record, so when you hit the while statement it has moved onto the second result.